# Can I affect an element outside the div I am currently in purely with CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, radio-button

**Context**: I am attempting to use the **radio hack** to toggle what text is viewed within the `.tabinfo` div, but my radios and the text whose `display` attribute I want to change are located in different divs.

**Problem**: Is it possible to use pure CSS selectors to select the `#text` element by clicking on a nested radio?

**Reference Code**: I am using the bootstrap layout and have created the following HTML code:

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs">
    <label for="tab1">Foo</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
    <label for="tab2">Bar</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs" checked> 
    <label for="tab3">Foo Bar</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="tabinfo">
        <div id="text1">
        </div>
        <div id="text2">
        </div>
        <div id="text3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
label {
    border: solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-color: rgb(211,211,205);
    border-width: 2px;
    color: rgb(12,174,175);
    background-color: rgb(247,247,247);
}

input:checked + label {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: rgb(94,94,94);
}

label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tabinfo {
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgb(211,211,205);
    border-width: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#tab1:checked ~ .col-xs-12 .tabinfo #text1,
#tab2:checked ~ .col-xs-12 .tabinfo #text2,
#tab3:checked ~ .col-xs-12 .tabinfo #text3 {
    display: block!important;
}
```

As you probably already guessed, the above does not work since the `#text`s and the `#tab`s are located in different divs. Is there any workaround or any solution without breaking the Bootstrap layout?

Comment: what specific 'text' should each radio input affect? Can the HTML be changed at all? And, incidentally, only one radio input, of a group which share a common `name`, attribute can be `checked`.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I just wrote the above code. Each numbered tab should affect the number text i.e. if #tab1 is checked, #text1 is shown et. al. The HTML can be changed as long as it doesn't break the bootstrap layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brittle solution can be used, but this involves moving the `<input>` elements away from the `<label>` elements, and you specify one requirement of any HTML changes is that any change

> …does not break the [Bootstrap] layout.

I don't *think* my changes break that layout, but I'm not entirely sure, so you will need to evaluate this yourself.

That preamble aside, however, I've modified your HTML to the following:

```
<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" />
<input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs" />
<input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs" />
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <label for="tab1">Foo</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <label for="tab2">Bar</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <label for="tab3">Foo Bar</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="tabinfo">
    <div id="text1">
    </div>
    <div id="text2">
    </div>
    <div id="text3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This approach allows us to take advantage of the `<label>` element's ability to check/uncheck its associated `<input>` element regardless of where in the document it may be located (so long as the `for` attribute identifies the `id` of that associated `<input>`); placing the `<input>` elements ahead of the content allows us to use sibling combinators to find the elements containing the relevant content to style.

On the assumption that you wish to retain the visual effect of the `<input>` being checked, or otherwise, we've also used CSS generated content to emulate a checked or unchecked radio; this could use some fine tuning, though:

```css
/* Here we hide all <div> elements within the .tabinfo
   element, and also all <input> elements whose 'name'
   attribute is equal to 'tabs' and whose 'type' is
   equal to 'radio': */

.tabinfo div,
input[name=tabs][type=radio] {
  display: none;
}


/* This styles the generated content of the ::before
   pseudo-element to show the attribute-value of the
   element's 'id' attribute; purely for the purposes
   of this demo: */

div[id^=text]::before {
  content: attr(id);
}


/* Styling the generated content, the ::before pseudo-
   element, of the <label> elements, in order to
   emulate the moved radio <input>: */

label::before {
  /* An empty string, content is required in order for
     the pseudo-element to be visible on the page: */
  content: '';
  /* To allow the pseudo-element to have specified
     width and height values: */
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  /* To include the border, and any padding, widths
     in the calculations for the element's size: */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #999;

  /* In order for the pseudo-radio to have a round
     shape/border: */
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
}

/* This selector styles the <label> element whose 'for'
   attribute is equal to 'tab1', which is a child of
   the div.col-xs-2 element which itself is a general
   sibling of the #tab1 element when that element is
   checked; this is the 'checked' style of the pseudo-
   'radio' generated content: */
#tab1:checked~div.col-xs-2>label[for=tab1]::before {
  background-color: #666;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #fff;
}

/* This selects the element with an id of 'text1',
   inside of a <div> with the class of 'col-xs-12',
   which is a general sibling of the '#tab1' element
   when that element is checked: */
#tab1:checked~div.col-xs-12 #text1 {

  /* Here we make the content of that element visible: */
  display: block;
}

#tab2:checked~div.col-xs-2>label[for=tab2]::before {
  background-color: #666;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #fff;
}

#tab2:checked~div.col-xs-12 #text2 {
  display: block;
}

#tab3:checked~div.col-xs-2>label[for=tab3]::before {
  background-color: #666;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #fff;
}

#tab3:checked~div.col-xs-12 #text3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" />
<input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs" />
<input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs" />
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <label for="tab1">Foo</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <label for="tab2">Bar</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <label for="tab3">Foo Bar</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="tabinfo">
    <div id="text1">
    </div>
    <div id="text2">
    </div>
    <div id="text3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5wpuLz7t/1/).

As you can see from the rules formed to show the elements related to the checked `<input>` elements those rules require some precision and repetition, since CSS has no concept of `this`, so, given a `data-affectedby` attribute whose value might be set to the `id` of the related `<input>`, there's no way we can have a rule along the lines of:

```
input[id^=tab]:checked ~ .col-xs-12 [data-affectedby=this.id]
```

Comment: This is a exactly what I was opting for. Thank you very much for your reply. I actually managed to find a workaround myself which didn't break the Bootstrap layout but most likely is considered a "hack". I used the bootstrap's classes and removed the divs, assigning the classes to the labels and the final div meaning my final output was something like this: https://pastebin.com/0jB4cr84

Answer (score 0):

This will be very difficult (perhaps impossible) when working with divs on different levels.

If you flatten the HTML structure a little you might be able to achieve something close to what you are looking for. Note though, it means getting rid of most of the Bootstrap helper layout divs.

Example HTML:

```
<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab1">Foo</label>

<input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab2">Bar</label>

<input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs" checked> 
<label for="tab3">Foo Bar</label>

<div id="text1" class="tabinfo">text1</div>
<div id="text2" class="tabinfo">text2</div>
<div id="text3" class="tabinfo">text3</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
label {
  border: solid;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-color: rgb(211,211,205);
  border-width: 2px;
  color: rgb(12,174,175);
  background-color: rgb(247,247,247);
}
input:checked + label {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: rgb(94,94,94);
}
label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tabinfo {
  display:none;
}
#tab1:checked ~ #text1{
  display:block;
}
#tab2:checked ~ #text2{
  display:block;
}
#tab3:checked ~ #text3{
  display:block;
}
```

See the example I made here: https://plnkr.co/edit/DyID8me4bM7VPCI9l6Cg?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your input. I understand that a solution exists without the nested divs, I just wanted to know if I could find a solution with the nested divs. Thank you very much for your answer though! I will wait to see if it actually is impossible and if so, mark your answer as correct (Due to being the first pointing out it is impossible).